# How do I pass a context name into a url call in my template html django

Tags: python, html, django

This is the urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name='index'),
   path('blog/', views.blog, name='blog')
]
```

This is the views.py file

```
def index(request):

    # Home
    home = Home.objects.latest('updated')

    # About
    about = About.objects.latest('updated')
    profiles = Profile.objects.filter(about=about)

    # Skills
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    # Portfolio
    portfolios = Portfolio.objects.all()
    

    context = {
        'home': home,
        'about': about,
        'profiles': profiles,
        'categories': categories,
        'portfolios': portfolios
    }


    if request.method == "POST":
        form_inst = FormFill(name = request.POST['name'],
                            email = request.POST['email'],
                            text = request.POST['text'])
        form_inst.save()
        return redirect('/')

    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

This is the html file where I am trying to pass each context name to the the navlink

```html
<div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
<ul class="nav__list">
   <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'blog' %}" class="nav__link active" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
   <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'index' {{home}} %}" class="nav__link">Home</a></li>
   <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'index' {{sbout}} %}" class="nav__link">About</a></li>
   <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'index' {{profiles}} %}" class="nav__link">Skills</a></li>
   <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'index' {{categories}} %}" class="nav__link">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'index' {{portfolios}} %}" class="nav__link">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to pass the context dictionary keys in the URL of each nav link in the html file

Comment: You don't need the braces, `{% url 'index' home %}` will pass `home` from the context to the tag. Your `index` view does not take any arguments though, this will probably error

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the objects themselves in the urls, you can only pass parameters like the primary key of your models, or strings, or numbers.

In your case you do not need to pass any parameters, because your views don't need them. The url alone is enough. You then write a view for each of your use cases and inside each view you get the needed objects from the database, pass them into context and then render the view.

So for your portfolios as an example:

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    path("/portfolios", views.portfolio_list, name="portfolio_list"),
    ....
]

#views.py
def portfolio_list(request):
    portfolios = Portfolio.objects.all()
    context = {"portfolios": portfolios}
    return TemplateResponse(
        request, template="portfolio_list.html", context=context
    )

#home.html
....
<li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'portfolio_list' %}" class="nav__link">Portfolio</a></li>

#portfolio_list.html
#list all your portfolio objects here
```

Edit: If you want to re-use the same template for multiple lists, then you could do that if all your objects are similar like so:

```
#urls.py
    urlpatterns = [
        ....
        path("list/<str:type>", views.list_view, name="list_view"),
        ....
    ]

#views.py
    def list_view(request, type):
        if type == 'portfolio':
            objects = Portfolio.objects.all()
        elif type == 'category':
            objects = Categories.objects.all()
        #
        # carry on with 'elif' for the other types you want to list
        # 

        context = {"objects": objects}

        return TemplateResponse(
            request, template="list_view.html", context=context
        )

#home.html
    ....
    <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'list_view' 'portfolio' %}" class="nav__link">Portfolios</a></li>
    <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'list_view' 'category' %}" class="nav__link">Categories</a></li>
    ....
```